# Nancy and abstract base module class / creating phantom class instance

Tags: reflection, abstract-class, nancy

I'm building a small application with Nancy

I want to have a kind of base class, that other modules can inherit from.
See below (there is a reason this isn't an abstract class, which I'll explain below)

```
public class ImportModule<T> : NancyModule
{
    protected ImportModule()
        : this(typeof(T).Name.ToLower())
    {
        Get["/"] = _ => "need to select an action - xxx";
        Get["/importnew"] = _ => ImportNew(); //note - method omitted for brevity
    }
}
```

When I run my app, I get

> Unable to resolve type: My.NameSpace.TypedImporter`1

**As a sidenote, if the `ImportModule` class is abstract, this doesn't happen**

Ok-
Now, I could have a class like this:

```
public class MyCustomImporter : ImportModule<MyCustomType>
{
   //overrides.... 
}
```

But, elsewhere, in a "DefaultImportModule" I have the following:

```
var importerModule = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ImportModule<>).MakeGenericType(type));
```

So I need to be able to create a type of importer, based on a type that's passed in

(Basically, if a user hits the url /customer, it's doing the same as a class like this would)

```
public class CustomerImporter : ImporterModule<Customer>
{
}
```

So, as I see it, I have two choices:
1) Stop nancy trying to map my ImportModule
2) Instantiate a "phantom class" that inherits from ImportModule and make ImportModule abstract again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a discussion in the Nancy group that may be related to your problem, it is certainly related to the non-abstract base modules not being recognised by Nancy. Here is what Andreas Håkansson had to say:

> Nancy locates everything that's inheriting NancyModule and assumes
>   it's something it can instantiate. Nancy is aware that it cannot
>   create an instance of an abstract module. So if you have a base-module
>   that's not abstract then Nancy will attempt to new it up. I'd like to
>   think that for 99% of the time, having a non-abstract base class is a
>   broken design.

And here is the link to the discussion:[Unable to resolve type: Nancy.Routing.DefaultRouteResolver](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/nancy-web-framework/abstract/nancy-web-framework/ghb6avyauEI/UawQycmcjmcJ)